# Can you build on top of every vehicle?

Tags: unturned

E.g. can I build on quads? Racecars? Or is the capability limited to a chosen few vehicles?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is as it said in the [Vehicles category in the Unturned Wiki](http://unturned.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Vehicles):

> n the latest version of Unturned 3.0, it is possible to build on top of and inside vehicles the same way you can build on the ground; that is, you can put Barbed Wire, Sandbags, Crates, etc. on or in your vehicle. Be aware, though, that doing this will change the handling characteristics of the vehicle; stacking too much stuff on the roof can make it very unstable, and adding lots of weight will make it accelerate and turn more slowly. Also note that other players can't stand atop moving vehicles, making roof-shooting impractical.